# Outlook fails to download any message over 3 MB

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My [Outlook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) fails when trying to download any message/attachment which is larger than 3 MB and will not download any more emails until I go into my Internet email account and delete that message. It is then fine until another large email tries to download to Outlook.

This is happening on an Windows XP machine with Outlook 2000 and a Windows 7 machine with Outlook 2003. I am running [McAfee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McAfee_VirusScan) on both machines.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "*Outlook fails*"?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Is it exactly 3MB?  Does 2.9MB download fine for example? Or is it just 'about' 3MB?

Comment: When I say Outlook fails I mean that it will not download any more emails, but everything else continues to work.

Comment: Can't be sure of exactly 3Mb, but it has failed on 3.1Mb

Comment: I don't get an error message it just says send/receive completed even though I know that messages have not been brought in.  However it will decide to bring in several copies of a past email even though it has been deleted

Comment: I have same problem here. Had email in inbox with 11MB attachment. In webmail i already receive the mail. But in outlook with POP, there is no email. I using outlook 2011 for mac.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably caused by a POP3/IMAP filter in your unspecified McAfee product that holds back all data until it has been received completely and finally analyzed. This leads to timeouts. Try if disabling filtering helps. If it does, raising timeout limit as already suggested by Josh will work around this problem. The problem is not a failing connection establishment however, it is a connection receiving no response for a too long time.

Comment: I have already tried setting the time out to the maximum of 5 minutes without sucess

Comment: And Outlook fails (how?) within *less* than 5 minutes after trying to fetch new mail? Did disabling filtering in your McAfee product (which one?) help?

Comment: Although the timeout is set to 5 mins the incoming message failed after less than 1 min with the error code below. Outlook fails by stopping from importing any further email until I delete the large one vie internet webmail. It gives an error code 0x800CCC0F.  I am using McAfee Internet Security Suite and have contacted them to see if they can help.  I tried switching off the firewall and real time scanning, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your ISP (ESP?) is restricting the file size limit.

Comment: I am using POP3 on a btinternet ISP via a slow broadband connection.  I didn't have this problem until a few months back

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Diogo hmm I suppose so, unless the answer is that the ISP is restricting the file size limits :)

Comment: If that's the answer, then move your questions to a comment on the main question and edit the answer to state the restricted file size.

Comment: I'm following the guidelines of the FAQ. Whether you're not interested in wasting your time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue before...  Try this:

Navigate to your email account settings, select the email account in question, and click `Change...`

In the next window, click `More Settings...` and then click the `Advanced` tab.

In the section titled `Server Timouts`, move that slider to adjust the timeout to be longer.

Basically, time is allotted to establish a connection with your mail server.  If a connection cannot be made in the allotted time, Outlook throws a connection error.  This is where you can adjust that allotted time.

I understand that you are not necessarily having issues with the initial connection.  However, I have run into connection issues with larger attachments where adjusting this setting has proven successful.

Comment: Thanks Josh, but have tried this and it didn't help

Comment: Have increased the timeout to 10mins to be sure.  Will see if it helps.  Thanks

Comment: Increasing timeout didn't help.  After less than 1 minute of the 10 set it came up with error 0x800CCC0F connection to server was interupted.